# does anyone use APE server?

Tags: ajax, mootools, server-side, ape

i am trying to figure out how to work with Ape, but there are some things in the chat demo code that i dont understand and cant find nothing about it in the documentation.
here is the code:

```
var userlist = new $H;

Ape.registerHookCmd("connect", function(params, cmd) {

if (!$defined(params.name)) return 0;
if (userlist.has(params.name.toLowerCase())) return ["005", "NICK_USED"];
if (params.name.length > 16 || params.name.test('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', 'i')) return ["006", "BAD_NICK"];


cmd.user.setProperty('name', params.name);

return 1;
});

Ape.addEvent('adduser', function(user) {
userlist.set(user.getProperty('name').toLowerCase(), true); 
});

Ape.addEvent('deluser', function(user) {
userlist.erase(user.getProperty('name').toLowerCase());
});
```

on the first line when userlist is define what is that $H? i cant find anything about it in the documentation and on the forth line userlist.has, where can i read about this .has, i understand what it means but im thinking maybe there are more commands like that.
if anyone has worked with ape and can help me with this, it would help me very much.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a MooTools Hash: http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Native/Hash

Comment: I receommend to get rid of it on the server side and use standard JS objects for that purpose. You kan use "in" to check if keys exist and the get your values